# Regular expression fo parsing JSON arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, regex

I am writing a Java application where I have to extract information from a JSON file. I want to get every element of a JSON array using Regex. I found this expression `\[([^]]+)\]` which works only with non-nested arrays, but not for the example below.

```
list[
 0{
    somedata{...},
    sublist0[ 
       somedata(...), 
       somedata(...) 
       ],
    key: value,
},
 1{
    somedata{...},
    sublist1[ 
       somedata(...), 
       somedata(...) 
       ],
    key: value,
}, .... ,
N{
    somedata{...},
    sublistN[ 
       somedata(...), 
       somedata(...) 
       ],
    key: value,
}
],
somedata{...}
```

For this example, the expression matches element 0, sublist1, sublist2 ... sublistN and ignores the other elements from the elements. I am looking for the appropriate regular expression because I can't use any external libraries for this project. The elements' names may also vary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: Why not using jackson or gson?

Comment: It is not allowed by the assignment